# does org.apache.aries.blueprint.preemptiveShutdown = false guaranties shutdown of bundles in start-level order

Tags: apache-felix, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf, aries

We have a shared service bundle running in our Karaf container and we would like shared bundle to go down last when we are shutting down container.

We would like to know if org.apache.aries.blueprint.preemptiveShutdown = false guaranties shutdown of bundles in start-level order  (one with higher start-level will be shutdown first ? )

Comment: hi!
have you managed to get a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Theorically, yes, this property disable the default behavior of blueprint aries when the container is destroyed. By default (or when this property is true), when the bundle 0 is stopped, then all blueprints containers are destroyed. with this property to false, the blueprint container are destroyed when the bundle are stopped by the framework, using the startlevel in reverse order.

But it's not "guaranteed". This kind of extender use often an asynchronous strategy : creating and destroying context can be handled by another thread. afaik, the current version of aries looks like to destroy the blueprint context synchronously when a bundle is stopped.